# sql query to laravel query with union

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

I want to convert the below union query to laravel query

```
DB::select("select lead_master.lead_stage from lead_master inner join  user_master on 
user_master.user_name=lead_master.assigned_user_name where region in (".$geo_string.") and teams 
in (".$filter_teams_string.") group by (lead_stage) union
select  meeting_hash from meetings_master where assigned_user_name in 
(".$filter_username_string.") and meeting_hash in ('follow_up','first_time') group by 
(meeting_hash) 
 union
 select sales_stage from opportunity_master where sales_stage in ('Identified','QO_to be 
 approved') and assigned_user in (".$filter_username_string.") group by (sales_stage)");
```

below query woeking fine in postgre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before this start, I assume that you understand about [laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent)

Assume your `lead_master` **table** is `LeadMaster` **Model** , also the `MeetingsMaster` and `OpportunityMaster`

```
$lead_master = LeadMaster::select("lead_master.lead_stage as stage")
    ->join('user_master','user_master.user_name','=','lead_master.assigned_user_name')
    ->whereIn('region',$geo) //$geo is an array
    ->whereIn('teams',$filter_username) //also an array
    ->groupBy('lead_stage');

$meetings_master = MeetingsMaster::select('meeting_hash as stage')
    ->whereIn('assigned_user_name',$filter_username)
    ->whereIn('meeting_hash',['follow_up','first_time'])
    ->groupBy('meeting_hash');

$opportunity_master = OpportunityMaster::select('sales_stage as stage')
    ->whereIn('sales_stage',['Identified','QO_to be approved'])
    ->whereIn('assigned_user',filter_username)
    ->groupBy('sales_stage');

$query = $lead_master->union($meetings_master)->union($opportunity_master)->pluck('stage'); //your result
dd($query);
```

So thats how its look like when you using **Laravel Eloquent**

**ps : You don't need to make 3 variables for that, I just use it to easy handle for maintenance**

Comment: Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [lead_stage] => PGL ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [lead_stage] => first_time ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [lead_stage] => Identified ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [lead_stage] => follow_up )  ) ) my output as above I want toget array(PGL,first_time,Identified,follow_up  )